# grub not working after installing Ubuntu 20.04 in a dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10 by following [this guide](https://www.linuxtechi.com/dual-boot-ubuntu-20-04-lts-along-with-windows-10/).

Grub is not working. Windows 10 is booting by default. Entering BIOS I have the following options to boot:

```
UEFI: Built-in EFI shell # I don´t know what it is, perhaps shell from BIOS?
SATA2: DVDRAM  
SATA5: MX500SDD1 # leads to Ubuntu
SATA1: TOSHIBA DT01ACA200 # HDD no OS installed, storage only
UEFI OS (P4: MX500SSD1)  # leads to Windows 10
Windows Boot Manager (P4: MX500SSD1) # leads to Windows 10
```

I used `#` to make comments about the available booting options.

In Windows 10, Fast Boot is unchecked.

To make it clear, I can access both OSs through BIOS booting selection (`SATA5: MX500SDD1` option leads to Ubuntu) so both OSs are functional.

A few days ago I had a previous dual boot installation of Windows 10, Ubuntu 18.04 in HDD Toshiba. I did a clean installation of Ubuntu 20.04 along that Windows 10 without any issues. I bought the MX500 SSD and ask my provider to install Windows 10, leaving some space to install Ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot mode (I have done this several times in the past, with Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 without any issues).

I understand that this issue can be solved by restoring grub, however I am not experienced enough to do this by myself. I would appreciate any guides on this.

Specs:

- mobo: MSI 970A-G43 (MS-7693)
- CPU: AMD FX 8350 8core 4GHz
- GPU: Sapphire Radeon RX 580 8GB PULSE
- RAM: CML8GX3M1A1600C10 Corsair 8GB 1600MHz DDR3
- HDD: TOSHIBA DT01ACA200
- SDD: CT1000MX500SSD1
- Monitor: LG 29um69g‑b

I checked that Windows 10 is in UEFI mode. In Boot-Repair -> *GRUB location* tab I have two separate partitions. One is sdb6 `/boot` partition, and the other one is sdb1 `/boot/efi` partition. Both are checked. Is this OK?

[image]

Comment: The first answer, I am not sure how to determine the names of sdX | sdXX | sdXXX  to run the script. For the second answer, sudo update-grub && sudo reboot did not work, Boot Repair aplication gives an error: The current session is in BIOS-compatibility mode. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.

Comment: I checked that windows is in UEDFI mode. in boot repair -> GRUB location I have two separate partitions: one is /boot parition (sdb6), the second is /boot/efi partition (sdb1). both are checked. Is ok?

Comment: https://imgur.com/tDF0CXG  
https://imgur.com/lBMUW0G
https://imgur.com/h5x1bZa

Comment: Better to post link to summary report. Most Ubuntu desktops do not need a separate /boot partition. It just becomes another partition to manage, size & how full. Some server type installs may need /boot partition. Often better to have smaller / (root) and then larger /home or data partition(s). Since UEFI system & UEFI installs, always boot live installer or Windows repair flash drive in UEFI boot mode.

Comment: I have tryed making installation with and without /boot partition. The result is the same